# How did they do grouping for nodes?

Tags: node-editor

As I was going through some tutorials online, I bumped into this way of creating the nodes.

Looking at the textures node, I noticed it's being grouped?
How is this done, or what's the rational behind all these?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

What you are seeing is a layout feature called **frames**. The rationale behind them is to help organize your node tree by helping you easily select and relocate related nodes all at once.

For clarity's sake, it may be important to distinguish node groups from frames, since you asked about groups in the question.

The Blender Manual says this about *Node Groups*:

> Grouping nodes can simplify a node tree by allowing instancing and
>   hiding parts of the tree. Both material and composite nodes can be
>   grouped.
>
> Conceptually, grouping nodes allows you to specify a set of nodes that
>   you can treat as though it were “just one node”. Node groups are
>   similar to functions in programming. You can then reuse them inside,
>   which are then called “NodeGroups”, or in other blend-file(s), when
>   appending called “NodeTrees”.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/texture_node/types/groups.html

And it says this about *Frames*:

> The Frame node is a useful tool for organizing nodes by collecting
>   related nodes together in a common area. Frames are useful when a node
>   setup becomes large and confusing yet the re-usability of a Node Group
>   is not required.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/frame.html

You can create a node group by selecting multiple nodes and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd>. You can create a frame by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> to "add" a new node, and go down to the bottom of the list, to *Layout*, and select *Frame*. You can give your frame a name by entering one in the *Label* field, found in the Properties Shelf to the right (if the Shelf isnt' visible press <kbd>n</kbd> while hovering your cursor in the Shader Editor). 
[image]

After creating the frame, you can drag the the desired nodes into it. Then you can click and drag the frame to move all of the nodes within it.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (shortcut for grouping nodes)

Comment: Ctrl-J is used to create a frame, this is the correct shortcut to use as the question picture shows frames. However it can be confusing as grouping in the sense of creating a group is done using [Ctrl-G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3SdB.png)

Answer (score 1):

This setup looks like it was created using the Node Wrangler add-on (built-in). Enable it in preferences, and with the Principled BSDF selected, press ctrl+alt+t to open an entire set of PBR textures at once (gives grouped nodes like image above). Or simply press ctrl+t for just a basecolor with a texture coordinate and mapping node attached. It is a very good add-on, and there are a multitude of time-saving features I haven't mentioned. I suggest you look into it more deeply for the full set of features.

If you want to set up the groups manually, in the shader editor select Add > Layout > Frame

Comment: thank you guys!